# ClusterManager multiple styles for ClusterItems markers of Google maps v2 utils

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, marker, markerclusterer, android-maps-utils

I've found that there is a way to change ClusterItem render options, customizing them this way:

```
clusterManager.setRenderer(new OwnIconRendered(getApplicationContext(), getMap(), clusterManager));
```

OwnIconRendered should extend DefaultClusterRenderer.

But, it changes all of the markers in one style. I need different styles options for different ClusterItems.
I've tried to add markers in clusterManager collection manually, but then clustering doesn't work.

```
MarkerManager.Collection markerCollection = mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection();
for(MyMarker marker: markerList){
markerCollection.addMarker(getMarkerOptions(latLng, marker.getLabel(), marker.getType()));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. Clustering with different icons works great. First, I had to add some fields to my ClusterMarker class which implements ClusterItem.

```
public class ClusterMarker implements ClusterItem {
private final LatLng latLng;
private MyMarker myMarker;

...
public void setMyMarker(MyMarker myMarker) {
    this.myMarker = myMarker;
}
}
```

MyMarker class has some info for styling markers, tilte and id's.

Later in the code I simply add markers to the ClusterManager instance this way:

```
mClusterManager.addItem(clusterMarker);
```

In OwnIconRendered class I overrided **onBeforeClusterItemRendered** method where all marker styling happening and in **onClusterItemRendered** method I added tags to markers, so later I could identify markers on map on clicking event.

```
public class OwnIconRendered extends DefaultClusterRenderer<ClusterMarker>  {
...
cunstructor
...

@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(ClusterMarker item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

    MyMarker myMarker = item.getMyMarker();

    markerOptions.icon(myMarker.getIcon());
    markerOptions.title(myMarker.getLabel());
    markerOptions.anchor(0.5f, 1);
    super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
}

@Override
protected void onClusterItemRendered(ClusterMarker clusterMarker, Marker marker) {
    marker.setTag(clusterMarker.getPlaceMarker().getItemId());
    super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterMarker, marker);
    clusterMarkerMap.put(marker, clusterMarker);
}
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution